# Octopus Deploy JSON Configuration Variable Feature not working

Tags: json, variables, deployment, configuration, octopus-deploy

I must be missing something simple with this JSON Configuration Variable feature.  I have the following JSON:

```
 {
  "EventProcessorFactory": "Factory"
  "HubConfiguration": [
    {
      "ArchiveStorageConnectionString": "Connection string"
      "ArchiveStorageContainerName": "containerName"
      "EventHubGroupName": "ehs-peds-dev"
    }
  ],
  "HeartBeatConfiguration": {
    "EventHubGroupName": "GroupName",
    "EventHubName": "HubName"
    "SharedAccessKey": "AccessKey"
    "SharedAccessKeyName": "EventPublishers",
    "EndPointURL": "URL"
  }
}
```

I want to replace the ArchiveStorageConnectionString (and other properties of HubConfiguration) but I can't figure out what the correct syntax is.  HubConfiguration is an array of HubConfigurations (although in this case I only have 1).

I've tried

```
HubConfiguration:1:ArchiveStorageConnectionString
```

But that doesn't work.  I've also tried

```
 HubConfiguration:0:ArchiveStorageConnectionString 
 0:HubConfiguration:0:ArchiveStorageConnectionString 
 1:HubConfiguration:1:ArchiveStorageConnectionString
```

but none of this seem to work.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Octopus code that matches and replaces the variables is here:

https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Calamari/blob/949008eaaafb8865305c7760e8f8448a5eaabb1a/source/Calamari/Integration/JsonVariables/JsonConfigurationVariableReplacer.cs

Some unit tests are here:

https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Calamari/blob/949008eaaafb8865305c7760e8f8448a5eaabb1a/source/Calamari.Tests/Fixtures/JsonVariables/JsonConfigurationVariableReplacerFixture.cs

I would have expected this to work:

```
HubConfiguration:0:ArchiveStorageConnectionString
```

There does seem to be a problem with your JSON - this line should end with a ,:

```
"EventProcessorFactory": "Factory"
```

Do you get any output in your deployment when the convention runs?

Comment: Sorry slow to respond.  I fixed it when I figured out the json was wrong, which is what you spotted.  Thanks for the answer though!